# Custom List View multiple item selecting

Tags: android, mysql, listview, android-intent, checkbox

Am new to development and have doubt in selecting listview items using android.

I have an listview with list of data from mysql and also have checkbox for selecting items and have button to pass the selected items to next screen.

What i want to know is how to select multiple items and send to next activity using the button.

Awaiting for your kind reply.

Comment: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-multiple-selection-listview/

Answer (score 0):

Perfect tutorial for your problem, might it will help you

[ANDROID: MULTIPLE SELECTION LISTVIEW](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-multiple-selection-listview/)

Comment: Dear John, Thanks for your kind reply... i got some idea with the link which was provided by you.. What the thing want to know means am retrieving data from mysql server, so what are all the steps want to do for the same...